# Makefile Syntax unclear

Tags: makefile

This is my first Makefile, and I am can't figure out some of the syntax used. The questions are marked below.

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c  $(BUILD_DIR) 
  $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@
```

1. What is the usage of "$(BUILD_DIR)" in the dependency?
2. What is the meaning of "$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@" in the role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most computer languages the syntax of make cannot be clear if you don't know it. If you are using GNU make the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is your friend. In the following explanations I will assume that `BUILD_DIR = build` and that one of the source files is `bar/foo.c`.

1. `$(BUILD_DIR)` in the list of prerequisites (dependencies) tells make that the build directory (in which object files are supposed to go) must exist before the recipe is executed; logical. There must be another rule somewhere to create the directory if it does not exist yet. Something like:

   ```
   $(BUILD_DIR):
       mkdir -p $@
   ```

   But unless you forgot to copy an important character, this dependency is terribly sub-optimal. As the last modification time of a directory changes each time its content changes (files or sub-directories added or removed), it will force the re-compilation of all source files every time the directory changes, which is not what you want. A better dependency would be [order-only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

   ```
   $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c | $(BUILD_DIR)
   ```

   that tells make to consider only the existence of `$(BUILD_DIR)`, not its last modification time, when deciding to re-build or not.
2. `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@` is just a combination of make [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) and [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Functions).

   - `$<` and `$@` expand as the first prerequisite (`bar/foo.c`) and the target (`build/bar/foo.o`) respectively.
   - `$(<:.c=.lst)` replaces `.c` by `.lst` in `$<`: `bar/foo.lst`.
   - `$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst))` removes the directory part: `foo.lst`.

All in all, for a `bar/foo.c` source file, and with `BUILD_DIR = build`, the pattern rule would be equivalent to:

```
    build/bar/foo.o: bar/foo.c | build
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/foo.lst bar/foo.c -o build/bar/foo.o
```

Note that there are two different situations to consider:

1. All your source files are in the same directory as the Makefile (no `bar/foo.c`, just `foo.c`). Then you can simplify your recipe:

   ```
   $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(<:.c=.lst) $< -o $@
   ```

   because the `$(notdir...)` is useless.
2. Your source files can be in sub-directories (`bar/foo.c`). Then you need the `$(notdir...)` in your recipe. But be warned that if you have two source files with the same base name (`bar/foo.c` and `baz/foo.c`) you will have a name conflict for `$(BUILD_DIR)/foo.lst` and your Makefile will not work as expected. Moreover, the order-only prerequisite of the rule should be equivalent to `build/bar` (or `build/baz`), not just `build`. And there should be a rule to create it if needed. If it is your case I suggest to change your pattern rule for:

   ```
   $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
       mkdir -p $(dir $@)
       $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@
   ```

   There are other solutions (secondary expansion...) but there are a bit too complicated for this already too long answer.